# how to add text to a 3D file on server side

Tags: node.js, linux, 3d

I have a few 3d models on obj format and I have to custom with a text that I recive on API. On a browser, I can use for example three.js and I can add the text easily. But on API server, I have tried to use three.js but it doesn't work, so How could I add a text to 3d obj file and save it all in a server? I can use nodejs, php, c# with net core, c++... any tool and language that works on linux, because I need it to integrate in an API REST of backend.

Comment: What is the file format?

Comment: The format of 3d file is .obj

Comment: By text you mean a 3d text object somewhere in the model?

Comment: Imagine that 3d objet is tennis ball, a eiffel Tower, a car... and the objet has a plain surface. So I would like to add the 3d text or the top, or the rigth bottom corner... or in the plain surface ( I know the coordinates of each object). I would like to add the name of player of game as the text. On three.js set the string and font, it add 3d text to object. I need to replicate the same but on the server side.